# error: ‘screen’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope, private-members

I'm having troubles with C++.
I am making an Engine class for my game that handles graphic using SDL.
The Engine class is (hopefully correctly implemented) Singleton.

**engine.h**:

```
#ifndef H_ENGINE
#define H_ENGINE

#ifndef H_SDL
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#endif

class Engine {
public:
    static Engine *getInstance(); //This returns the singleton object of class
    int init(int screenWidth, int screenHeight); //must initialize before use
    ~Engine(); //destructor

private:
    Engine(); //private constructor
    static Engine *instance; //stores the single instance of the class
    SDL_Surface *screen; //Struct for SDL
};

#endif
```

**engine.cpp**:

```
#include "engine.h"

Engine *Engine::instance = NULL;

Engine::Engine() {
    screen = NULL;
}

Engine *Engine::getInstance() {
if(instance == NULL)
    instance = new Engine();

return instance;
}

int init(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

//This line has the error: error: ‘screen’ was not declared in this scope
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(screenWidth, screenHeight, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

return 1;
}

Engine::~Engine() {
SDL_Quit();
}
```

**main.cpp**: contains the line

```
Engine::getInstance()->init(600, 400);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Singletons = BAD. This is extremely bad. Don't. Ever.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to put the class qualifier on `init`:

```
int Engine::init(int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
```

Happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You define `init` as:

```
int init(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
```

However, this defines a function in global scope (there there is no `screen` variable).

Instead, if you write:

```
int Engine::init(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
```

You will define the function of your class.